# NFC: How can I tell my app to open a vCard instead of Contact app?

Tags: android, nfc, vcf-vcard

I have been playing nicely with NFC, and really happy with the result.

The question I have now is how wan I handle a vCard that is written on a tag?

I have set those lines in the Manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

        <data android:mimeType="text/vcard" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

but seems useless: every time I scan the tag, the contact application opens.

Thank  alot for any link or advise!

Comment: Have you disabled the contact app from 'default launch', have the correct permission in app, and how are you verifying that the tag is setup correctly?

Comment: 1) I have removed all default from contact apps. 2)Tag is setup correctly because the default contact app open correctly.

Comment: This seems to work:             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: I'm curious to know what is the actual mimeType encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter for *both* **text/vcard** and **text/x-vcard**:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/vcard" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have seen both being used in NFC tags. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcard#Media_type), text/x-vcard is deprecated.

Comment: That's what I said in previous answer 23h ago, but thanks ;-)

Comment: My point is that you should filter for both possible mime-types. It wasn't clear to me that you meant that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

The mimeType of the vCard is in fact:

**text/x-vcard**

Problem magically solved.